# bash parameter expansion as arguments to command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm having difficulty trying to pass a bash parameter to `find` as arguments.

Best explained via code:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release

$ find /etc -path '*/init.d' 2>/dev/null | wc -l
2

$ args="-path '*/init.d'"
$ echo $args
-path '*/init.d'
$ find /etc $args 2>/dev/null | wc -l
0

$ set -x; !!
set -x; find /etc $args 2>/dev/null | wc -l
+ wc -l
+ find /etc -path ''\''*/init.d'\'''
0
```

Where are the extra `''` quotes coming from in the `set -x` output?

I've tried a number of different ways to get this to work but haven't had success so far. This guide seems to indicate that this should be possible, since parameter expansion takes place before command execution: http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png

Comment: The diagram you linked to is good, inasfar as it goes, but even its author describes it as a _simplified_ explanation. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser for something with fewer details elided.

Comment: That's just what `set -x` does it prints out with single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array:

```
args=( -path '*/init.d' )
find /etc "${args[@]}"
```

The reason the other approach doesn't work is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). In short: Quote characters are handled during syntax parsing -- **before** parameter expansion occurs. Thus, when quote characters come *from* parameter expansion, they're not parsed as syntax, but treated as any other data: Run through string-splitting and glob expansion, and passed through to the program being run.

The extra quotes/escaping in `set -x` output are just how the shell tells you that your primary quotes are data, distinguishing them from quotes that are present as syntax.

Comment: This works, thanks! I had tried using an array, but kept it as a string, eg: `args=("-path '*/init.d'")`. I suppose that failed for the same reasons.